# How to offset a box shadow with margin between it and the element it relates to

Tags: css

Simple question but I am stuck:

How can I offset a box shadow so it has a margin between it and the element it relates to? Is this even possible? I was thinking some trick with pseudo-elements?

```
box-shadow: inset 5px 0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Are there some other attributes I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a transparent border:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red padding-box;
  border:10px solid transparent;
  box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or padding if you want to use an inset shadow:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red content-box;
  padding:10px;
  box-shadow:  0px 0px 10px inset rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or pseudo element like you said:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  margin:5px;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:-5px;
  left:-5px;
  right:-5px;
  bottom:-5px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there an option where I can offset the box shadow without moving the position of the element it relates to?

Comment: @alias51 the pseudo element solution is doing this, the main element will not move